# UIViewController in Xcode 5 - Outlet not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, iboutlet

I running the latest version of Xcode 5 and OSX 10.9.4. I am a newbie when it comes to Xcode.

I am trying to make buttons with a rectangular rounded border which apparently has been removed in iOS 7 from a simple UI object.

My work around is to create a UIController View Class and link my button to the class via an outlet with using the control drag method. But when I drag it over from the storyboard to the .h file of the class it does not automatically generate the outlet.

I have tried creating a new Objective-C Class that extends ViewControler and UIViewController, and have found that I cannot control drag the button to make an outlet for either class.

I was wondering if anyone else was experiencing this same issue or if they know what I am doing wrong.

**Solution in Detail:**

- Create New Objective-C Class that is subclass of UIViewController (ViewController no longer supported)
- Under Show the Identity inspector (seen below)
- Add name of class created in step in Class box under Custom Class (seen below)

**Note:** It may show as a grey text of the class you want. You want to fill it out and make sure it is a solid black.

Comment: Did you assign your view controller class to view controller on storyboard? I've found that even if you assign it, sometimes you will need to clean your project or reopen xcode to be able to perform drag'n'drop feature.

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Check Karthi's answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether ViewController in nib have a proper reference to ViewController.h[image]

[image]

Make sure that reference has been made properly with viewcontrollers in nib file.

Comment: Is there any way to automate this?

Comment: In StoryBoard there is no automated way, you need to configure it manually. But if you create xib, while creating xib with ViewController automatically does the configuration for you.

Comment: What if I want an object in StoryBoard to work with more than one class? How would I go about that?